# Stripe: Get total successfully paid invoices count

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using stripe for subscription. Where i need to fire an event after 3 successfully charges.
For this i am using **invoice.payment_succeeded** webhook.
But there is no  key which specify the number of this recurring payment means whether it is first or second or nth charge. So how could i get the number of successfully payment made on a subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [`https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list) API endpoint with the customer's ID, the `status` parameter set to `paid` and optionally, the subscription parameter and then count how many invoices were returned.

There are some other parameters, like `limit`, `starting_after`, etc. that you can send it too.

The [`invoice.payment_succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded) webhook sends the [invoice object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object) in the `data.object` field so you should be able to get the `customer` and `subscription` values from it.

I'd recommend doing the `invoices` call asynchronously to ensure that the webhook call doesn't time out.

Answer (score 1):

FYI there is an expand to it, like with the current node api;

```ts
const ret = await stripe.invoices.list(
    {
      expand: ["total_count"],
      limit: 0,
  });
console.log(ret.total_count)
```

It can be called with `${url}?expand[]=total_count&limit=0` too, if you need to write it by hand.

<s>I did not found this in the documentation, but some libs using it, and it is indeed works. (But be careful, if it is not documented it could stop working too.)</s>

Here is the docs; https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination/search#search_pagination-total_count

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as it is stated in the answer by D Malan, you can use the https://api.stripe.com/v1/invoices endpoint.

Though there is one thing to keep in mind when retrieving data from Stripe.

You can only get 100 items per call. Therefore, if you had recurring payment that generates more than 100 invoices after some time, you wouldn't be able to get the total count in one call. I suggest storing invoices/payment intents to your database and then using your DB engine to count the results.

Keep in mind that you should listen to `invoice.payment_succeeded` event in order to keep your database in sync, if you store the invoice or payment intent beforehand, while its status is not `paid` or `succeeded`, respectively.